# Return dash graph from AJAX call

Tags: javascript, python, flask, graph, plotly-dash

I'm trying to create an application that uses flask/dash to create a graph and display it in my HTML. However, I seem to be stuck.

My code looks as following:

innit.py:

```
# Create a Flask app
server = Flask(__name__)
bootstrap = Bootstrap5(server)

# Define a route to generate the Dash graph
@server.route('/create_graph', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def get_graph():
    # Define some sample data
    x_values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    y_values = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]

    # Create a graph using the data
    graph = dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph',
        figure={
            'data': [
                {'x': x_values, 'y': y_values, 'type': 'line', 'name': 'Example Graph'}
            ],
            'layout': {
                'title': 'Example Dash Graph'
            }
        }
    )

    # Convert the graph to a JSON string and return it
    return json.dumps(graph, cls=plotly.utils.PlotlyJSONEncoder)

# Define a route to render the HTML template that contains the JavaScript code and the container div for the graph
@server.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

# Run the app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    server.run(debug=True)
```

script.js:

```
$("#test").click(function () {
    var data_input = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/create_graph",
        data: JSON.stringify(data_input),
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            var graph = Plotly.d3.json(data, function (data) {
                Plotly.newPlot('graph-location-1', data);
            });
        },
    })
})
```

This displays an empty graph in my div with id "graph-location-1". I get two messages:

plotly-latest.min.js:20     GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/%5C%5Bobject%20Object%5C%5D 404 (NOT FOUND)

and

plotly-latest.min.js:61 WARN: Calling Plotly.plot as if redrawing but this container doesn't yet have a plot.

How can I fix this? Or should I use an alternative way of creating plots and displaying them in my HTML?

Thanks!!

Comment: Warning: I know nothing about javascript.  However, I would be suspicious of this line "var graph = Plotly....."  This seems to be creating something and storing, or referencing it with variable 'graph'  But you do not use 'graph' anywhere.  And, in any sensible coding language, graph will go out of scope and be destroyed almost as soon as created.

Comment: Since you're using dash why don't you use dash callbacks to create/update graphs? Is there a particular reason you're trying to update the graphs via Flask?

Comment: @ravenspoint In this case it doesn't matter that it goes out of scope because the call is just for updating the DOM. `graph` doesn't have ownership over the actual graph, but the assignment indeed doesn't make sense, I'd remove it.

Comment: @5eb no particular reason, I'm not too familiar with both techniques. Do you have any suggestion for an alternative solution? I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: You can look at this example https://dash.plotly.com/minimal-app. In the example the figure is updated with a callback. A callback runs when an input changes. In the example the input is the current selected value of a dropdown, when it changes the figure is updated. In your case you could have your `test` button inside the layout of your dash app and have it as an input to a callback that updates your figure.

Comment: If you want the application to still be a Flask application, but you want it to contain a dashboard you can embed a Dash app inside Flask, see this article https://hackersandslackers.com/plotly-dash-with-flask/. But just using Dash alone might be enough depending on your use-case.